# elastic search implement in running laravel application

Tags: mysql, laravel, elasticsearch

i'm using "Laravel" application. "Mysql" as database.

now i"m planning to implement elastic search. please let me know,how can i implement elastic search in running "Laravel" application without changing code too much ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use official library Elasticsearch-PHP or it's wrapper for Laravel (e.g. check link nr. 1), also its useful to use query builder for searches (e.g. link nr. 2).

Please take a look on these:

1. https://github.com/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch - wrapper for laravel
2. https://github.com/ongr-io/ElasticsearchDSL - elasticsearch query builder

Comment: we have successfully using them in our product

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21047074)

Comment: @skrx, I don't know how to explain to use some library, I gave particular library which are working..